# Azure CLI - How to get ResourceId of an storage container?

Tags: azure-cli, resource-id

I am trying to run this command

```
Set-AzSqlDatabaseAudit `
>> -ResourceGroupName "" `
>> -ServerName "" `
>> -DatabaseName "" `
>> -BlobStorageTargetState Enabled `
>> -StorageAccountResourceId "?"
```

To setup auditing on SQL database but I am not able to find a way how to get resource id of storage container I already created for this purpose. I don't see this property in the GUI and also I don't know how to retrieve it via CLI.

Is there some general way how to get resource id of an object or where do I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `Set-AzSqlDatabaseAudit` you are using is [azure Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/?view=azps-5.7.0), not [azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/), so if you want to Powershell to get the `StorageAccountResourceId`, just use the command below.

```
(Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -Name <storageaccount-name>).Id
```

[image]

If you want to use azure CLI, just use [`az storage account show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_account_show), the `id` is what you want.

```
az storage account show --resource-group 'xxxxx' --name 'xxxxx'
```

[image]